# Retrieve all facebook photos in an album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I did a FQL query with the following query...

```
SELECT album_object_id, src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id = xxx
```

It returned me 4 photos only. However, I actually have 7 photos in that album. From most of the solutions I found online, many mentioned it is regarding privacy issue. However, I have checked that all photos in that album are set to Public.

The other 3 photos are posted at a different timing from the earlier 4 photos though. But they are set to Public too!

Comment: What is the album type? Run this Graph API query to check: `ALBUM_ID?fields=type`

Comment: Does anybody found an answer to this using Graph API?